# unable to run the application after changing the project facet?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have changed my project facet and added dynamic web module to it, but after that I am unable to run the application and getting err0r : 404. I have attached the screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share web.xml please.

Comment: if it run fine before, why did you add the web module facet?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is due to adding of Dynamic Web Project. After you have added the Dynamic web module to your project, Eclipse created the directory called WebContent in your application. This is not something that Maven likes. Select the project in eclipse and press `Alt + Enter` to show up the project properties. Search for `Deployment Assembly` and click on the Add button and select "Folder". Click on "Next". Select the folder `/src/main/webapp` and click on Ok. Make sure that the Deploy path col for this directory is '/'. Now you can delete the WebContent folder created by eclipse and your project can run on Server